# Retry request 5 times and show error message

Tags: ios, swift

I've created below function using the Moya Framework. However if the request fails. i would like to retry the request 5 times and after that show an alert. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
func checkToken() {
    testProvider.request(.validateToken(Defaults[.accessToken], Defaults[.clientId], Defaults[.uId])) { result in
        switch result {
        case let .Success(response):
        do {
            try response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()

            //Validate token

            let storyBaord = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let mainController = storyBaord.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! TabBarController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainController, animated: true)

        }
        catch {

           //delete token and push to log in
            Defaults.remove(.accessToken)
            Defaults.remove(.clientId)
            Defaults.remove(.uId)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PushToWelcomeScreen", sender: self)

        }


        case let .Failure(error):
           //No internet connection/server error ->
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a timer with repeat for 6 times, to a function with some index will do the trick.
If you success just invalidate the timer.
If that function get called with an index of 6, display an alert